# How to explain what this list is doing

Tags: python, list

Could somebody explain to me what is happening in this section of code?

```
FIELDLENGTH = 20 
FIELDWIDTH = 35

Field = [[SOIL for Column in range(FIELDWIDTH)] for Row  range(FIELDLENGTH)]
Row = FIELDLENGTH // 2
Column = FIELDWIDTH // 2
Field[Row][Column] = SEED
return Field
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: Well for starters, those aren't arrays.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't familiar with list comprehensions in python, you can read up here:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

I love list comprehensions, as they are an easy way to alter or filter lists.

In the case for your code, it looks like we have a length and a width. From there we use the list comprehension to fill a "Field" with "Soil" that has the same length and width dimensions. Then we put a "Seed" in the middle of the "Field" and return the "Field" that contains the "Seed".